# LINQ - Searching one to many for exact match of array

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Let me preface by saying that this is self study and I am trying to self learn LINQ and Entity Framework. I've spent a few days attempting to turn the SQL statement at the bottom of this question into LINQ with terrible results. I've also included the SQL diagram at the bottom.

My goal is to select all stories that have the same characters as the passed in string array. I'm not wanting stories returned that have additional characters or missing characters.  This is what my feeble LINQ skills have come up with so far:

```
var characters = new string[] { "Harry", "Tom" };
var cq = _context.TblCharacter.AsNoTracking().Where(c => characters.Contains(c.NameVc));
var q = from c in cq
        join sc in _context.TblStoryCharacter.AsNoTracking()
         on c.IdI equals sc.CharacterIdI
        join s in _context.TblStory.AsNoTracking().Include(s => s.TblStoryCharacter).ThenInclude(sc => sc.CharacterIdINavigation)
         on sc.StoryIdI equals s.IdI
        where s.TblStoryCharacter.Count() == characters.Length
        where s.TblStoryCharacter.Where(sc => characters.Contains(sc.CharacterIdINavigation.NameVc)).Count() == characters.Length
        select s;
```

The above code is spawning a bunch of queries (SQL profiler image below) and is loading a bunch of objects into memory. Is there any LINQ magic for this scenario?

[image]

LINQ spawned queries:

```
SELECT [t0].[StoryId_i]
FROM [tbl_story_character] AS [t0]

SELECT [sc1].[StoryId_i]
FROM [tbl_story_character] AS [sc1]
INNER JOIN [tbl_character] AS [sc.CharacterIdINavigation0] ON [sc1].[CharacterId_i] = [sc.CharacterIdINavigation0].[Id_i]
WHERE [sc.CharacterIdINavigation0].[Name_vc] IN ('Harry', 'Tom')
```

And this is the SQL I started out trying to convert to LINQ:

```
select *
from tbl_story
where Id_i in (
    select sc.StoryId_i
    from tbl_story_character sc
    inner join tbl_character c
        on c.Id_i = sc.CharacterId_i
    where   c.Name_vc   in ('Harry', 'Tom')
    and     not exists (
        select *
        from tbl_story_character subsc
        inner join tbl_character subc
            on subc.Id_i = subsc.CharacterId_i
        where   subc.Name_vc    not in ('Harry', 'Tom')
        and     subsc.StoryId_i = sc.StoryId_i
    )
    group by sc.StoryId_i
    having count(*) = 2
)
```

Database diagram:
[image: Story DB Diagram]

EDIT:
The models were generated by EFCore based on an existing database, each model contains navigation properties based on the foreign keys in the diagram.

New LINQ after taking advice of Jon Skeet and Munzer.

```
from s in _context.TblStory.AsNoTracking()
          .Include(s => s.AuthorIdINavigation)
          .Include(s => s.TblStoryCharacter)
                  .ThenInclude(sc => sc.CharacterIdINavigation)
where s.TblStoryCharacter.All(sc => characters.Contains(sc.CharacterIdINavigation.NameVc))
where s.TblStoryCharacter.Count == 2
select s;
```

This results in the following SQL which seems correct.

```
SELECT [s].[Id_i], [s].[AuthorId_i], [s].[Published_dt]
FROM [tbl_story] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [tbl_author] AS [t2] ON [s].[AuthorId_i] = [t2].[Id_i]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [tbl_story_character] AS [sc]
    INNER JOIN [tbl_character] AS [sc.CharacterIdINavigation] ON [sc].[CharacterId_i] = [sc.CharacterIdINavigation].[Id_i]
    WHERE ([s].[Id_i] = [sc].[StoryId_i]) AND [sc.CharacterIdINavigation].[Name_vc] NOT IN ('Harry', 'Tom')) AND ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [tbl_story_character] AS [t]
    WHERE [s].[Id_i] = [t].[StoryId_i]
) = 2)
ORDER BY [s].[Id_i]
```

Comment: I would start off by trying to simplify the query to a shorter example that still shows the problem. Can you reproduce the problem with just *one* join, and one filter? Basically, find out where it starts blowing up.

Comment: Looking at the "LINQ spawned queries", I would say you are using EF Core, which definitely is not a good tool for (complex) queries currently. But your LINQ query looks strange with all that mixture of manual joins, navigation properties, tracking an eager loading related constructs. You've already shown the database diagram, but for EF queries it's more important to have the entity model (classes) of the involved tables, could you please post it?

Comment: @IvanStoev Should I perhaps move away from core until it is a bit more mature? I don't have any limitations that require me to utilize core.

Comment: EF6 is for sure better when it comes to queries. Have to try Core 2.0, they say they improved a lot in that area, but I can't say whether it's true or not before trying myself.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the knowledge

Comment: You are welcome. Just one more thing - using LINQ like SQL (as both current answerers do) with EF is just waste of time and does not benefit from one of the most beautiful EF features - navigation properties. See [Don’t Use LINQ’s Join. Navigate!](https://dzone.com/articles/don%E2%80%99t-use-linq%E2%80%99s-join-navigate). Cheers.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I ported the dotnetcore app to asp.net EF6 and have to say the performance is completely different. EF6 performance is much better for the same LINQ queries that I was having issues with using EF core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for here

it should be something like this

```
var q = from c in cq
        join sc in _context.TblStoryCharacter.AsNoTracking()
         on c.IdI equals sc.CharacterIdI
        join s in _context.TblStory.AsNoTracking().Include(s => s.TblStoryCharacter).ThenInclude(sc => sc.CharacterIdINavigation)
         on sc.StoryIdI equals s.IdI
        where s.TblStoryCharacter.All(sc => characters.Contains(sc.CharacterIdINavigation.NameVc))
        select s;
```

Comment: I used your LINQ query but needed to add this also in order for the correct SQL to be used: where s.TblStoryCharacter.Count == 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = {"Harry", "Tom"};

            var results = (from sc in Story_Character.story_character
                           join chr in Character.character on sc.Id_i equals chr.Id_i
                           join st in Story.story on sc.Id_i equals st.Id_i
                           join auth in Author.author on sc.Id_i equals auth.Id_i
                           where names.Contains(chr.Name_vc)
                           select new { sc = sc, chr = chr, st = st, auth = auth })
                          .GroupBy(x => x.sc.StoryId_i).Where(x => x.Count() >= 2).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Story_Character
    {
        public static List<Story_Character> story_character = new List<Story_Character>();
        public int Id_i { get; set; }
        public int StoryId_i { get; set; }
        public int CharacterId_i { get; set; }
    }

    public class Character
    {
        public static List<Character> character = new List<Character>();
        public int Id_i { get; set; }
        public string Name_vc { get; set; }
    }
    public class Story
    {
        public static List<Story> story = new List<Story>();
        public int Id_i { get; set; }
        public DateTime Published_dt { get; set; }
        public string Title_vc { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId_i { get; set; }
    }
    public class Author
    {
        public static List<Author> author = new List<Author>();
        public int Id_i { get; set; }
        public string Name_vc { get; set; }
        public string Url_vc { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: This will correctly identify stories that have Harry and Tom as characters but  I think will also include stories that have Harry, Tom, + other random character(s). Correct?

Comment: Each Id_i has only one character name since Id_i is a primary key.  So it is impossible to have any other character names.  Now it is possible the two id_i have the same character name.  I don't think there is a need to test x.Count() >= 2.